# AngularJS How to set value of variable

Tags: angularjs

I need to show/hide a tab based on the value of JSON, i.e. If the value of Region (In JSON, 'Region':'US') is equal to US in at least one of the items within JSON response I should show the tab, if not hide...

I'm using the following code to check if at least the item.region has US value, I'm able to read the values from the JSON but when I try to set the value to true to a variable inside the tag I don't get the value in the variable

```
<span ng-repeat="item in res.objects" ng-if="item.region === 'US'">
                // Set myVariable = true
</span>
```

And after the variable has been set, display the div with ng-show and the value of the bool variable.

```
<div class="action-tab" ng-click="res.viewUS()" ng-show="<valueOfBoolVariable">
                View US
</div>
```

Is this good approach to accomplish this? Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t think this is aligned to how angular works... unless I’m completely wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish here. If the second code block is supposed to be inside the ng-repeat, then this is correct only that you don't need the ng-show on the inner element if your using the ng-if.

Comment: I should read all the json elements to know if at least the region = US is present once, if I put the second block inside the ng-repeat I will have as many divs as elements with region = US are in the JSON but I just want to show a tab when the region = US not all the times... That's why I thought to read the JSON and set a variable to true in case this value has been found... if not the variable will be false and no tab will be displayed.

Comment: @CarlosM: Even though you could do it, any way you are trying to set value for variable or handle the logic directly on the template is completely wrong. Your HTML is supposed to read your JSON data and render it, simple. All of logic which you want to achieve, you have to modify and put them into your logic JS until you get the final array that you want and pass it to HTML by $scope. If you want to send an good email to your friend, you should prepare your content well and give it to the postman, the postman is not supposed to modify your content, his job is to send to the desired address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `ng-init` it allows you to evaluate an expression of your current scope

```
<span ng-repeat="item in res.objects" ng-if="item.region === 'US'">  
    <!-- Evaluate your variable -->
     <div ng-init="evaluate(item)"> </div>
</span>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.evaluate = function(item){
 //you do the job
}
```